# Trying to create grails project using maven

Tags: maven, grails, maven-archetype

I ran this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.grails \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=grails-maven-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.3.4 \
-DgroupId=example -DartifactId=my-app
```

when it completed. Then:

```
cd my-app
mvn initialize
```

I got this response:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project example:my-app:grails-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.grails:grails-dependencies:jar:2.3.4 in http://repo.grails.org/grails/core was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of grails has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

This is all boiler plate stuff. I went to the main grails repo and I can see the dependency, so why is maven still complaining? I am on Ubuntu 13.10, with Oracle JDK 1.7, maven 3.0.4

All help appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependency for the grails-dependencies to pom

That should fix your problem.